# Custom ComboBox not closing properly

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

I am trying to make my custom ComboBox inheriting from ContainerControl. I used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30958/How-to-create-a-custom-ComboBox-from-scratch) article as a base but rewrote it, but I use a ToolStripControlHost, my own custom ListBox & a ToolStripDropDown.

Now the ComboBox is a button where you click on to show the DropDowncontaining my ListBox, works fine with overriding OnMouseClick.

The problems starts when I try to close the DropDown, with the DropDown's 'AutoClose' property to true, the DropDown closes if you click somewhere outside the DropDown (including the button) ...

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseClick(e);
        /* listboxControl = ToolStripDropDown */
    if (!listboxControl.Visible)
    {
    listboxControl.Show(this, GetDropLocation(), ToolStripDropDownDirection.BelowRight);
            //listbox.Capture = true;
    }
}
```

This is the code for the click on the button .. so what happens if you click it ?
If the DropDown is shown, it first closes the DropDown, then it fires the OnMouseClick event. Meaning: listboxControl.Visible is already false & it will show the DropDown again. All of this causing a quick close-open.

I have been stuck with this problem for some time now and google doesn't seem to know a lot about this subject (that article on CodeProject has the same bug).

What I have tried is disabling AutoClose and capturing the mouse after I show the DropDown, this works partially but it affects the working of my hosted ListBox. The ListBox contains a set of controls (the items), these items have a hover paint effect. Capturing the mouse in the ListBox control prevents the OnMouseEnter to be fired.

All input would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable to track the cursor position when the DropDown is closing.

Here is a quick and dirty example control:

```
public class CustomDropBox : Control {
  private ListBox box = new ListBox() { IntegralHeight = false };
  private ToolStripControlHost host;
  private ToolStripDropDown drop;
  private bool wasShowing = false;

  public CustomDropBox() {
    box.MinimumSize = new Size(120, 120);
    box.MouseUp += box_MouseUp;
    box.KeyPress += box_KeyPress;
    box.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" });
    host = new ToolStripControlHost(box) { Padding = Padding.Empty };
    drop = new ToolStripDropDown() { Padding = Padding.Empty };
    drop.Closing += drop_Closing;
    drop.Items.Add(host);
  }

  private Rectangle GetDownRectangle() {
    return new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - 16, 0, 16, this.ClientSize.Height);
  }

  void drop_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.AppClicked) {
      wasShowing = GetDownRectangle().Contains(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
    } else {
      wasShowing = false;
    }
  }

  void box_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter && box.SelectedIndex > -1) {
      drop.Close();
    }
  }

  void box_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    int index = box.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (index > -1) {
      drop.Close();
    }
  }

  protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && GetDownRectangle().Contains(e.Location)) {
      if (wasShowing) {
        wasShowing = false;
      } else {
        drop.Show(this, new Point(0, this.Height));
      }
    }      
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    ControlPaint.DrawComboButton(e.Graphics, GetDownRectangle(), ButtonState.Normal);
    base.OnPaint(e);
  }
}
```